# Simplify this expression involving Gamma function

Tags: real-numbers

Simplify $\dfrac{2a\cdot\Gamma(2a)}{\Gamma(2a+1)}$.

Where $a$ is any positive real number.

Comment: Is $a$ a natural number?

Comment: @some1, no a is positive real

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty simple. Check Gamma function definition [for help](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html). Or look into spoilers for solution.

> Actually, this requires only one equation related to Gamma function:
>  $$\Gamma(1 + z) = z\Gamma(z)$$
>  So, the expression equals to $1$.

Comment: thanks for your help.your answer confirmed some of my results.